# How do I write a function that returns the first 5 positive even numbers?

Tags: javascript, function

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function even(num) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=1; i<num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 === 0) {
            newArr.push(num[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
  
console.log(even(myArr));
```

My function throws an exception when called. How can I rewrite or refactor the above code to return the first 5 positive numbers?

Comment: Your code works perfectly.

Comment: ... though you probably should start the loop index at 0 instead of 1, it works here because the first element is odd.

Answer (score 3):

You can create it this way.

```js
var myArr = [1,2,0,3,4,-6,5,-3,88,21,-6,5,6,7,8,9,10];

let evens = myArr.filter(x => x > 0 && x % 2 == 0).slice(0, 5);

console.log(evens)
```

Comment: zero is not an even value ?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: Good, but why is it important for this topic?

Comment: Don't worry I voted a +, let's say I'm a bit of a precision freak. in the meantime I also wondered if zero was positive or not, and I realized that in JS `Math.sign(0)` returns zero, ie neither `+1` and nor `-1` ....

Comment: BTW, if zero isn't even, your answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your code appears to work. Can you give an example of the error that is occurring? Second off, if you want a function that returns an array of the first n positive, even integers, you can write something like this.

```
function firstEven(count) {
  var response = []; // Create the response list
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++) { // Loop for number of even numbers you want
    response.push((i + 1) * 2); // *2 skips every two numbers, and +1 shifts the number to even
  }
  return response
}
```

However, if you want to just filter out all odd numbers from an array, you can do the following.

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var myEvens = myArr.filter(function(myNum) { // Filter runs the function for every value in the array, and (if the function returns false) it removed that value
  return (myNum % 2) == 0;
});
```

Feel free to ask if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

2 others differnts ways

```js
const myArr = [1,2,3,4,-6,5,-3,88,21,-6,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const even_1 = arr => arr.filter(x=>(x>=0 && !(x&1))).slice(0,5)

const even_2 = arr => 
  {
  let r = []
  for(x of arr) 
    if (x>=0 && !(x&1)) // test2 = boolean AND on bit zero
      {
      r.push(x); 
      if (r.length >= 5) break;
      }
  return r
  }


console.log('even 1:', even_1(myArr).join(','))
console.log('even 2:', even_2(myArr).join(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion:

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

function even(numbersArray) {
  var first5EvenNums = [];
  for (const num of numbersArray) {
    if (first5EvenNums.length >= 5) break;
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
      first5EvenNums.push(num);
    }
  }
  return first5EvenNums;
}

console.log(even(myArr));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
<script>

var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

  function even(num){
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=1; i<num.length; i++){
      if (num[i] % 2 === 0)
      {
        newArr.push(num[i]);
        if(newArr.length == 5){
            return newArr;
        }
      }
  
    }
  return newArr;
  };
  
  $("#test").text(even(myArr));
</script>
```

This return first 5 positive number in array.

Comment: This must be one of the most unnecessary usages of jQuery.

Comment: Bro, this code is perfect, because u need to understood the code "what u want" and how  "filter" work line by line.

yes u can use like this myArr.filter(x => x > 0 && x % 2 == 0).slice(0, 5); ofc

but u never understand what filter do, if u don't understand like u and u always ask this basic questions, have nice day.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. Your function doesn't even contain any jQuery code.

Comment: I mean, where does it say it has to be jQuery?